# How to save user input in to text file with Java?

Tags: java

I have code which takes user input, so I want to save that user input into a text file. I was searching for information, but I couldn't really find anything, maybe I just don't know how to properly search. I hope that you will give me some advise on how to find a solution for my problem, to save user input into a text file.

Comment: Search for "java write text to file".

Answer (score 0):

It's easy:

```
String inputFromUser = "Anything from User";
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("pathToSaveAndfilename.txt");
out.println(inputFromUser);
//When your file work is completed then don't forgot to close the file
out.close();
```

Comment: As I'm using OOP way, in Main class to make my code working I'm putting for example writeName() method, to ask for user input. But how can I get only the data which user inputed? So the idea is, how can I get data x from a method in main class.

Comment: File file1 = new File("out.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file1);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        pw.write(personInfo.writeName(););

Comment: @Maksimsx For getting user input from file you can use `FileReader`. Here is `FileReader` [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html).